# How to animate a Bootstrap toggle in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, animation, twitter-bootstrap-4

As you may now, Bootstrap toggles just change `display: none` to `display: block` and vice-versa. I've been reading the [Angular 2 Animation Guide](https://angular.io/guide/animations#example-entering-and-leaving) but it all seems to depend on a changing property on the component, when I just want to change based on the element's `style.display` property.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way, or how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations#example-entering-and-leaving), you can use the void and * states to define transitions that animate the entering and leaving of elements:

> Enter: void => * 
>   Leave: * => void

```
animations: [
   trigger('myAwesomeAnimation', [
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(1000)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(1000, style({opacity: 100}))
      ])
  ])   
]
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li  @myAwesomeAnimation *ngFor="let i of list">
   {{ i }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo Punkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/R6ogvHPWiktMlgiM9U8G?p=preview)

Comment: But that only applies when they are inserted or removed from the DOM, right? My problem is it's just the `display` attribute changing, but the markup is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using jquery to `toggle()` in the component, and just went the more Angular-idomatic way of using boolean properties with `*ngIf`. It cleaner and more declarative, and lets me use the `:enter` and `:leave` transitions.